# Integrating perf4j in log4j.properties - issue with appender-ref

Tags: java, logging, log4j, perf4j

I am integrating perf4j in log4j.properties...

## log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN ,  R

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=/logs/myLogs.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=20

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c] %m%n


log4j.appender.A=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A.File=/logs/myLogs_audit.log
log4j.appender.A.MaxFileSize=100000KB
log4j.appender.A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n


log4j.appender.perf=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.perf.File=/logs/myLogs_perfStats.log
log4j.appender.perf.Append = true
log4j.appender.perf.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.perf.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.perf.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.perf.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n


log4j.appender.CoalescingStatistics=org.perf4j.log4j.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender
log4j.appender.CoalescingStatistics.TimeSlice=10000

log4j.appender.CoalescingStatistics.appender-ref=perf

log4j.logger.org.perf4j.TimingLogger=info,CoalescingStatistics
log4j.additivity.org.perf4j.TimingLogger=false
```

## The error is :

```
log4j:WARN No such property [appender-ref] in org.perf4j.log4j.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender.
```

Can anyone help me reolve this? I cannot use log4j.xml.
Performance Logging is not getting publish in the file.